# WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/play/testroomcode [127.0.0.1:57522] Exception inside application: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'

Tags: django, typeerror, channel

**When I was trying to connect my websocket then it is showing this error:**

Error:

> WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/play/testroomcode [127.0.0.1:57522] Exception inside application: **call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'

The code inside my asgi.py :

```
import os
from django.urls import path
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from tictactoe.consumers import GameRoom
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'advancesource.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()    
ws_pattern = [
    path('ws/play/<room_code>', GameRoom)
]  
application= ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {

        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(
            ws_pattern
        ))
    }
)
```

The code inside my consumer.py :

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json    
class GameRoom(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_code']
        self.room_group_name = 'room_%s' % self.room_name
        print(self.room_group_name)

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.groups_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.groups_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.groups_send)(
            self.room_group_name,{
                'type' : 'run_game',
                'payload': text_data
            }
        )
```

In websocketking it is showing:

> Could not connect to "ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/tictactoe/play/testroomcode". You may be able to find more information using Inspector/Dev Tools on this page.

Comment: BUT I AM ENCOUNTERING A NEW ERROR
`'payload': data['data']
KeyError: 'data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the remedy.

I have changed my asgi.py :

```
    path('ws/play/<room_code>', GameRoom.as_asgi())
]
```